# Is it possible to get google maps voice directions inside of your app?

Tags: android, google-maps

Not really a specific code question per say, so if I need to move this, I will gladly do so. Just a simple question or two about what is possible.

Is it possible to close google maps app from my code after my code launched it? Seems like it's not to me.

if that's true, is there any way possible via google maps api to embed voice directions into an activity of mine instead of launching the google maps app so that it can be closed whenever I want? I know maps can be embedded, and even directions, but I can't find anything about voice and voice is the most important thing. Maybe that's why they don't seem to give that part out? thx

Comment: doing turn by turn directions while using google maps is against googles terms of services, you must use the maps app i you want directions or use another maps provider

Comment: Even I wanted to do the same thing but because of the google terms, I used an `onClickPolyline` and an intent to open google maps directly with my currently selected route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the real time navigation is prohibited by Terms of Service. Have a look at paragraph 10.4.c (iii) that reads

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

You should create an [intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) that opens the Google Maps app in navigation mode. There is a Google Maps URLs API that allows to construct a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps intents from your application. You can open navigation mode of native app following this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I create an intent for the gmaps app itself and use that. I was just wondering because I couldn't see it in the api. thanks